# API explorer/dashboard for Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

We have a number of micro-service REST APIs that use Swagger for documentation, each one implemented as a separate webapp. Does anyone know of a product that can be used to present an explorer or dashboard for all of these APIs, so that clients/users can just go to one URL to get the details of all of our APIs.

For example, we have:

```
http://wwww.blah.com/app1/api-docs
http://wwww.blah.com/app2/api-docs
```

But we'd like the ability to present a combination of both docs via a single URL.

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we do not provide such a tool in our own Swagger tool set, and we're probably not going to provide one for Swagger 1.2.

We're in the process of formalizing a solution for describing micro-services as part of Swagger 2.0 and I imagine Swagger-UI will follow with support for it. At the time of this answer, I cannot give an expected date for the solution and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

We use our API Gateway to publish services and in doing so, it mashesup the swagger.json into one unified swagger.  Works well.